# ng Select is not working in angular@14 the field is coming as blank

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular14, angular-ngselect

I have installed ng select veriosn 9.1.0 in my angular 14 and I'm not able to see the field in my browser as shown below.

[image]

both tpa and programs are searchable but it is blank
here is my code

```
       <div style="display: none;">
         <input type="text">
       </div>
     
       <ng-select [items]="exportPdfInstance.tpaDetails" ngDefaultControl [virtualScroll]="true" bindLabel="tpaName"
         bindValue="tpaId" (change)="changeLeagueOwner($event)" placeholder="Select Tpa" formControlName="tpa">
       </ng-select>
     </div>
     <div class="group_item p-relative d-grid">
       <label>Program</label>

       <ng-select [items]="exportPdfInstance.detailsProgram" ngDefaultControl [virtualScroll]="true"
         bindLabel="clientName" bindValue="programId" placeholder="Select Program" formControlName="program">
       </ng-select>
     </div
```

I'm getting the data from server

here is my package.json

[image]

it is working in different branch of my project i have created this from working branch but here it is not working

Comment: Any console error? What does the elemnts say in browser inspector?

Comment: Make sure you are importing it into the module where you are using it.

Comment: Please show us the corresponding ts-code. specially the form controls.